# WPF Complex Logic of Custom Controls with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, revit-api

I am creating a WPF-based plugin (for Revit, an architectural 3D modelling software, but this shouldn't matter) which is quite complex and I'm getting kind of lost.

The WPF `Window` is composed by 2 tabs and each `Tab` is a custom `UserControl` that I'm inserting in the `TabItem` through a `Frame`. The Main Window has a `ViewModel` where the data is bound.

One of the tabs helps with the creation of floors in a 3D model

**part of MainWindow.xaml**

```
<TabItem Name="LevelsTab" Header="Levels" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    <ScrollViewer >
        <Frame Name="LevelsContent" Source="LevelsTab.xaml"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</TabItem>
```

The *LevelsTab.xaml* `UserControl` is really barebone and just contains buttons to create or remove a custom UserControl I created to represent graphically a floor in the UI (screenshot below). This very simple as well:
**LevelDefinition.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="RevitPrototype.Setup.LevelDefinition" ....
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Level:"/>
    <TextBox Name="LevelName" Text={Binding <!--yet to be bound-->}/>
    <TextBox Name="LevelElevation"  Text={Binding <!--yet to be bound-->}/>
    <TextBox Name="ToFloorAbove" Text={Binding <!--yet to be bound-->}/>
</UserControl>
```

When the user clicks the buttons to add or remove floors in *LevelsTab.xaml*, a new `LevelDefinition` is added or removed to the gird.

Each `LevelDefinition` will be able to create a *Level* object from the information contained in the different `TextBox` elements, using MVVM. Eventually, in the ViewModel, I should have a `List<Level>` I guess.
**Level.cs**

```
class Level
{
    public double Elevation { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Each `LevelDefinition` should be sort of bound to the previous one though, as the floor below contains the information of the height to the Level above. The right-most `TextBox` in *LevelDefinition.xaml* indicated the distance between the current floor and the floor above, hence the *Height* `TextBox should just be the sum of its height PLUS the distance to the level above:
[image: UI]
Of course the extra level of difficulty here is that if I change distance to the level above in one floor, all the floors above will have to update the height. For example: I change LEVEL 01 (from the pic) to have 4 meters to the level above, LEVEL 02's height will have to update to become 7m (instead of 6) and LEVEL 03's will have to become 10m.

But at this point I'm very lost:

- How do I get this logic of getting the floor height bound to the info in the floor below?
- How do I implement MVVM correctly in this case?

I hope I managed to explain the situation correctly even though it's quite complex and thanks for the help!

Comment: To connect items you would need to use LinkedList but I would implement Parent and child properties on your LevelDefinition, then add childs height of the floor. If you want your window to perform stop using Label to display just a text, use TextBlock instead. Why do you use Frame? Also all those names are irrelevant unless you use an animation but there is no indication that you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to make your `Level` items editable, you have to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-5.0). I created a level view model for demonstration purposes and added a property `OverallElevation` that represents the current elevation including that of previous levels.

```
public class LevelViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      private string _name;
      private int _number;
      private double _elevation;
      private double _overallElevation;

      public LevelViewModel(string name, int number, double elevation, double overallElevation)
      {
         Number = number;
         Name = name;
         Elevation = elevation;
         OverallElevation = overallElevation;
      }

      public string Name
      {
         get => _name;
         set
         {
            if (_name == value)
               return;

            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
         }
      }

      public int Number
      {
         get => _number;
         set
         {
            if (_number == value)
               return;

            _number = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
         }
      }

      public double Elevation
      {
         get => _elevation;
         set
         {
            if (_elevation.CompareTo(value) == 0)
               return;

            _elevation = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
         }
      }

      public double OverallElevation
      {
         get => _overallElevation;
         set
         {
            if (_overallElevation.CompareTo(value) == 0)
               return;

            _overallElevation = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
         }
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
   }
```

You can bind these properties to your `LevelDefinition` user control. I adapted your sample, because it is incomplete. Since the overall elevation is calculated, I set the corresponding `TextBox` to be read-only, but you should really use a `TextBlock` or a similar read-only control instead.

```
<UserControl x:Class="RevitPrototype.Setup.LevelDefinition"
             ...>
   <UserControl.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
      </Style>
   </UserControl.Resources>
   <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Level:"/>
      <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="LevelName" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
      <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Name="LevelElevation"  Text="{Binding OverallElevation}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
      <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Name="ToFloorAbove" Text="{Binding Elevation}"/>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Since you did not provide your tab view model, I created one for reference. This view model exposes an `ObservableCollection` of levels, a `GroundFloor` property and commands to add and remove levels. I use a `DelegateCommand` type, but you may use a different one.

On each add of a level, you subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of the new level and on removal you unsubscribe to prevent memory leaks. Now, whenever a property changes on a `LevelViewModel` instance, the `OnLevelPropertyChanged` method is called. This method checks, if the `Elevation` property was changed. If it was, the `UpdateOverallElevation` method is called, which recalculates all overall elevation properties. Of course you could optimize this to only recalculate the levels above the current one passed as `sender`.

For a more robust implementation, you should subscribe to the [`CollectionChanged` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged?view=net-5.0) of the `Levels` collection, so can subscribe to and unsubscribe from the [`PropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=net-5.0) events of level items whenever you add, remove or modify the collection in other ways than through the commands like restoring a persisted collection.

```
public class LevelsViewModel
{
   private const string GroundName = "GROUND FLOOR";
   private const string LevelName = "LEVEL";

   public ObservableCollection<LevelViewModel> Levels { get; }

   public LevelViewModel GroundFloor { get; }

   public ICommand Add { get; }

   public ICommand Remove { get; }

   public LevelsViewModel()
   {
      Levels = new ObservableCollection<LevelViewModel>();
      GroundFloor = new LevelViewModel(GroundName, 0, 0, 0);
      Add = new DelegateCommand<string>(ExecuteAdd);
      Remove = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteRemove);

      GroundFloor.PropertyChanged += OnLevelPropertyChanged;
   }

   private void ExecuteAdd(string arg)
   {
      if (!double.TryParse(arg, out var value))
         return;

      var lastLevel = Levels.Any() ? Levels.Last() : GroundFloor;

      var number = lastLevel.Number + 1;
      var name = GetDefaultLevelName(number);
      var overallHeight = lastLevel.OverallElevation + value;
      var level = new LevelViewModel(name, number, value, overallHeight);

      level.PropertyChanged += OnLevelPropertyChanged;
      Levels.Add(level);
   }

   private void ExecuteRemove()
   {
      if (!Levels.Any())
         return;

      var lastLevel = Levels.Last();
      lastLevel.PropertyChanged -= OnLevelPropertyChanged;
      Levels.Remove(lastLevel);
   }

   private void OnLevelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (e.PropertyName != nameof(LevelViewModel.Elevation))
         return;

      UpdateOverallElevation();
   }

   private static string GetDefaultLevelName(int number)
   {
      return $"{LevelName} {number:D2}";
   }

   private void UpdateOverallElevation()
   {
      GroundFloor.OverallElevation = GroundFloor.Elevation;
      var previousLevel = GroundFloor;

      foreach (var level in Levels)
      {
         level.OverallElevation = previousLevel.OverallElevation + level.Elevation;
         previousLevel = level;
      }
   }
}
```

The view for the levels tab item could look like below. You can use a `ListBox` with your `LevelDefinition` user control as item template to display the levels. Alternatively, you could use a `DataGrid` with editable columns for each property of the `LevelViewModel`, which would be more flexible for users.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Levels}">
      <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
         </Style>
      </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <local:LevelDefinition/>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
   <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
      <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="-" MinWidth="50" Command="{Binding Remove}"/>
      <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="+" MinWidth="50" Command="{Binding Add}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=NewLevelElevationTextBox}"/>
      <TextBox x:Name="NewLevelElevationTextBox" MinWidth="100"/>
   </DockPanel>
   <local:LevelDefinition Grid.Row="2" DataContext="{Binding GroundFloor}"/>
</Grid>
```

This is a simplified example, there is no input validation, invalid values are ignored on adding.

Comment: Wow thanks @thatguy !! That's very impressive!
Is the LevelViewModel in addition to the Level class in my post or is it instead?
Also, should I have one ViewModel per tab, or one ViewModel for MainWindow that encompasses both tabs?

Comment: @AndreaTassera I my case I created it instead. However, there are different approaches, you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your model, you can create a separate `Level` model and a `LevelViewModel` type and copy the data each time or you create a view model type that _wraps_ your model, meaning you pass a model instance in the view model and store it there and adapt the getters and setter of the properties to act on the model internally. For the view model for tabs, it is preferable to create separate view models for each view or tab, which also favors using data templates.

Comment: @AndreaTassera For more information on data templates, you can refer to the [overview on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Thanks for info and for the solution. I adapted a few things to my needs and it works beautifully now!

Comment: do you have any links where I can understand better how to wrap the Level class with a LevelViewModel? So far I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged into the model but I'm not sure if it's the right thing and would like to understand better benefits of the approaches and best practice. Thanks!

Comment: @AndreaTassera There are various sources, e.g. [MVVM: To Wrap or Not to Wrap? How much should the ViewModel wrap the Model?](https://nathan.alner.net/2010/02/09/mvvm-to-wrap-or-not-to-wrap-how-much-should-the-viewmodel-wrap-the-model-part-1/) . I think you will find other related questions to creating and wrapping view models, too.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to implement this using a multi-binding converter.

Assuming that you set up the multi-converter as a static resource somewhere, the TextBlock to display the value is:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ElevationMultiConverter}">
            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                <Binding Path="" />
                <Binding Path="DataContext.Levels" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}" />
            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

The converter itself looks like this:

```
class ElevationMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var item = values[0] as Level;
        var list = values[1] as IList<Level>;
        var lowerLevels = list.Where(listItem => list.IndexOf(listItem) <= list.IndexOf(item));
        var elevation = lowerLevels.Sum(listItem => listItem.Height);
        return elevation.ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In this example, it depends on the specific order of items in the list to determine whether a level is above or below another; you could use a property, or whatever else.

I didn't use a framework for this example so I needed to implement INotifyPropertyChanged everywhere myself. In the MainViewModel, this meant adding a listener to each Level element's PropertyChanged event to trigger the multibinding converter to have 'changed'. In total, my MainViewModel looked like this:

```
class MainViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Level> Levels { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Levels = new ObservableCollection<Level>();
        Levels.CollectionChanged += Levels_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Levels_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(var i in e.NewItems)
        {
            (i as Level).PropertyChanged += MainViewModel_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    private void MainViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Levels)));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

How it works:
A new Level is added to the collection, and it's PropertyChanged event is listened to by the containing view model. When the height of a level changes, the PropertyChanged event is fired and is picked up by the MainViewModel. It in turn fires a PropertyChanged event for the Levels property. The MultiConverter is bound to the Levels property, and all changes for it trigger the converters to re-evaluate and update all of the levels combined height values.

Comment: Thanks Pete! It looks very concise and elegant! I'll do a bit of research on those topics as I'm not very familiar with IMultiValueConverter